# What does Heb 1:10 mean in light of the "throne" in Revelation?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, trinity, throne-of-god

**Premise: YHWH (God) made all things**

Isaiah 44:24 (NASB)

> Thus says YHWH, your Redeemer, and the one who formed you from the womb, “I, YHWH, am the maker of all things, **Stretching out the heavens by Myself and spreading out the earth all alone.**

Isaiah 45:18 (NASB)

> For thus says YHWH, who created the heaven  (*He is the God who formed the earth and made it, He established it and did not create it a waste place, but formed it to be inhabited*), **“I am YHWH, and there is none else.**

**Question:**

There seems to be a discontinuity within the popular interpretations of these next two NT passages. The first passage in Revelation 4, objectively makes the case that Jesus, the Lamb, is a distinct person and entity from the Lord God Almighty, YHWH, who is being worshiped as the Creator.

Revelation 4:8-11

> <sup>**8**</sup> And the four beasts had each of them six wings about him; and they were full of eyes within: and they rest not day and night, saying, Holy, holy, holy, Lord God Almighty, which was, and is, and is to come.
>
> <sup>**9**</sup>
> And when those beasts give glory and honour and thanks to **him that sat on the throne**, who liveth for ever and ever,
>
> <sup>**10**</sup>
> The four and twenty elders fall down before him that sat on the throne, and worship him that liveth for ever and ever, and cast their crowns before the throne, saying,
>
> <sup>**11**</sup> Thou art worthy, O LORD, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created.

In the next chapter, we read that the Lamb is in the midst of the throne with the elders.  He takes the scroll from the One being worshiped as the Creator of everything.

> <sup>**5:6**</sup>And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, stood a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth.

> <sup>**7**</sup>And he came and took the book out of the right hand of him that sat upon the throne.

**And now the verse in question...**

The author of Hebrews seems to be making a conflation between the Son and YHWH by quoting the OT Psalm 102.

Hebrews 1:10

> <sup>**10**</sup> And, Thou, Lord, in the beginning hast laid the foundation of the earth; and the heavens are the works of thine hands:

Psalm 102

> <sup>**25**</sup> Of old hast thou laid the foundation of the earth: and the heavens are the work of thy hands.

So there we have it... Two New Testament scriptures from two different authors seem to disagree with each other on the surface... at least from my literal interpretation.

According to Isaiah, there is only one YHWH and no other, and He is the One who created the earth alone.  How then can the LORD who sits on the throne be said to have created all things in Revelation, and yet the "Lord" (Lamb/Jesus) has "laid the foundation of all the earth" in Hebrews? How can one make sense of this? *Is it YHWH (God) or Jesus (the Lamb) on the throne?*

**What interpretation of Hebrews 1:10 agrees with the vision of the Lamb taking the scroll from the hand of the one being worshipped as the sole Creator?**

Please explain this so that our *knowledge of the only true God, **and** Jesus Christ, whom He has sent*" might increase. (John 17:3)

Comment: How can we make sense of ***what*** ? You say the two scriptures 'seem' to disagree. But they do not. You have not substantiated any 'disagreement'. That one, in humanity, is on the throne of God almighty, Revelation 4 and 5,  does not 'disagree' with Hebrews 1:10.

Comment: Sounds like you should provide the community with our first answer up for critique.  Because it appears you are the one who needs to substantiate " That one, in humanity, is on the throne of God almighty...." What does this even mean?  Please explain to the rest of us searching for answers to these questions.

Comment: I'm happy to supply answers, if you ask on-topic and substantial questions, as I have done, here, for several years.

Comment: Body of the question has been edited for clarity.

Comment: @NigelJ  Luckily for the children of God, there is no first come, first serve in the Kingdom.  In fact, our master says its exactly the opposite.

Comment: I have to wonder what translation the OP uses when it says " Thou art worthy O LORD(YHWH), to receive praise'' etc. It's a Greek text so why use a Hebrew designation for God?  Also I notice that many translators have simply "O Lord" while others include "our God" and this also appears in the original Greek. Or does it? Is there some text-based reason why translators omit "our God?"

Comment: @DanFefferman Who is being praised?  YHWH is being praised because He is who created everything.  I will removed the parenthesis and the name of God that I added for clarity.  Rather, it seems to have added ambiguity

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore. The replacement of YHWH to LORD blurred the 
distinction between the Father and the Son.”  That blurred distinction is sometimes used by some to advance a non-biblical teaching of a multi-person god. Even in heaven, Jesus/the Lamb has a God, hence, Jesus is not YHWH. “the construction of theophoric names, starting with the letters “Jeho” is evidence that God’s name is actually Jehovah, (and that Christ’s name is actually Jehoshua) …..”– Smith’s 1863 “A Dictionary of the Bible” Section 2.1

Comment: Well the letter J didn't exist til recent so God's name is more closely Yahowah or as it has been revealed be many including myself, Yahuah and His only begotten is Yahusha. Yes I agree that YHWH would be appropriate but I am quoting the scripture so I'll just let it speak for itself.  YHWH is obviously who is being praised in this verse.

Comment: Why is this question closed?  Mods ask me to clarify yet do not clarify how it isn't clear.

Comment: @curiousdannii  "Not suitable for this site"?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: This looks like a theological synthesis question rather than a exegetical question about a single passage. Please consider editing it to make it a clearer exegetical question about one passage

Comment: @curiousdannii This question is seeking the meaning of that biblical text (Heb 1:10) either in context(rev throne scene and premised Isaiah scripture about YHWH) or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation of it

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not permitted to ask questions here.  Rathe its telling me I need to improve my existing q's.  So... How can I improve this?  Its a question that I am very curious about?  I have no answer personally.

Comment: Can you do what I said in my last comment? But note that there are lots of very interesting questions about the Bible that are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Yes I responded on Feb 11th.   This question is about Heb 1:10 a single verse.   In the context of Isaiah and Rev.   What is the interpretation of this verse?  Thats all I'm asking.  I'm seeking ② the meaning of that biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation of it.  This is what is allowed here, am I wrong?

Comment: @curiousdannii Does Exegesis not include referencing other scripture for context?  I don't understand how this question is not Exegetical.

Comment: Yes you can reference other passages, but it should be clear that you are predominantly asking about one passage, and not asking for a synthesis of many passages. But I didn't even close this question! Try to edit it in such a way that you convince everyone it's about one passage.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ok... I think I fixed it. How bout now?

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to me that you made any substantial changes. There are still four books of the Bible being quoted, and the main question seems to be a theological one: how to resolve who the identity of the creator is in all those passages.

Comment: @curiousdannii Ok... so theological questions can never be exegetical questions?  You just said referencing other scripture is ok.  I am definitely asking about Hebrews 1:10.  Can you help me understand?